# SOAP UI Groovi_Csv data is not passed in input xml request

Tags: java, soap, groovy

I am using below groovy script where I wanted to pass the value from the CSV to the Get whether input xml request. But even I am able to read the values from the csv but these values are not successfully passed to input xml below is my code:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def csvFilePath = "C:/Users/hemant.varhekar/Desktop/Sprint/SOAPUI/New Text Document.csv"
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath))

rowsData = context.fileReader.readLines()
int rowsize = rowsData.size()
log.info rowsize

for(int i =0;  i < rowsize;  i++)
{

    rowdata = rowsData[i]
   String[] data = rowdata.split(",")
    log.info data[0]
    log.info data[1]


    groovyUtils.setPropertyValue("GetWeather111", "CityName1", data[0])
    groovyUtils.setPropertyValue("GetWeather111", "CountryName1", data[1])
    testRunner.runTestStepByName( "GetWeather111")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what this does -

```
groovyUtils.setPropertyValue("GetWeather111", "CityName1", data[0])
```

But according to me, you have to declare your request and then pass values into it. You haven't done that... 
declare you request as,

```
def request = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetWeather111#Request")
```

Now, inside your for loop use this (assuming the tag name is "CityName1",

```
request.setNodeValue("CityName1", data[0])
```

and so on, and after all the setNodeValues, use this and check your xml request :)

```
request.updateProperty()
```